# Set Django IntegerField by choices=... name

Tags: python, django, django-models

When you have a model field with a choices option you tend to have some magic values associated with human readable names. Is there in Django a convenient way to set these fields by the human readable name instead of the value?

Consider this model:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
  PRIORITIES = (
    (0, 'Low'),
    (1, 'Normal'),
    (2, 'High'),
  )

  priority = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=PRIORITIES)
```

At some point we have a Thing instance and we want to set its priority. Obviously you could do,

```
thing.priority = 1
```

But that forces you to memorize the Value-Name mapping of PRIORITIES. This doesn't work:

```
thing.priority = 'Normal' # Throws ValueError on .save()
```

Currently I have this silly workaround:

```
thing.priority = dict((key,value) for (value,key) in Thing.PRIORITIES)['Normal']
```

but that's clunky. Given how common this scenario could be I was wondering if anyone had a better solution. Is there some field method for setting fields by choice name which I totally overlooked?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Do as [seen here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/). Then you can use a word that represents the proper integer.

Like so:

```
LOW = 0
NORMAL = 1
HIGH = 2
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (LOW, 'Low'),
    (NORMAL, 'Normal'),
    (HIGH, 'High'),
)
```

Then they are still integers in the DB.

Usage would be `thing.priority = Thing.NORMAL`

Comment: That's a nicely detailed blog posting on the subject. Hard to find with Google too so thanks.

Comment: FWIW, if you need set it from a literal string (perhaps from a form, user input, or similar) you can then just do: thing.priority = getattr(thing, strvalue.upper()).

Comment: Really like the Encapsulation section on the blog.

Comment: I have a problem: I always see the default value on the admin! I have tested that the value really changes! What should I do now?

Comment: This is the way to go but beware: if you add or remove choices in the future, your numbers will not be sequential. You could possibly comment out deprecated choices so there won't be future confusion and you won't run into db collisions.

Comment: Note that the assignment can also be done in one, comprehensive line. I prefer doing so if there are only a couple of choices and they're enumerated from 0..n:
LOW, NORMAL, HIGH = 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 45):

As of Django 3.0, you can use:

```
class ThingPriority(models.IntegerChoices):
    LOW = 0, 'Low'
    NORMAL = 1, 'Normal'
    HIGH = 2, 'High'


class Thing(models.Model):
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=ThingPriority.LOW, choices=ThingPriority.choices)

# then in your code
thing = get_my_thing()
thing.priority = ThingPriority.HIGH
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what is the type of LOW in ThingPriority?

Answer (score 8):

I appreciate the constant defining way but I believe [Enum](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) type is far best for this task. They can represent integer and a string for an item in the same time, while keeping your code more readable.

Enums were introduced to Python in version 3.4. If you are using any lower (such as v2.x) you can still have it by installing the [backported package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34): `pip install enum34`.

```
# myapp/fields.py
from enum import Enum    


class ChoiceEnum(Enum):

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        choices = list()

        # Loop thru defined enums
        for item in cls:
            choices.append((item.value, item.name))

        # return as tuple
        return tuple(choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __int__(self):
        return self.value


class Language(ChoiceEnum):
    Python = 1
    Ruby = 2
    Java = 3
    PHP = 4
    Cpp = 5

# Uh oh
Language.Cpp._name_ = 'C++'
```

This is pretty much all. You can inherit the `ChoiceEnum` to create your own definitions and use them in a model definition like:

```
from django.db import models
from myapp.fields import Language

class MyModel(models.Model):
    language = models.IntegerField(choices=Language.choices(), default=int(Language.Python))
    # ...
```

Querying is icing on the cake as you may guess:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(language=int(Language.Ruby))
# or if you don't prefer `__int__` method..
MyModel.objects.filter(language=Language.Ruby.value)
```

Representing them in string is also made easy:

```
# Get the enum item
lang = Language(some_instance.language)

print(str(lang))
# or if you don't prefer `__str__` method..
print(lang.name)

# Same as get_FOO_display
lang.name == some_instance.get_language_display()
```

Comment: If you prefer not to introduce a base class like `ChoiceEnum`, you can use the `.value` and `.name` as @kirpit describes and replace the usage of `choices()` with `tuple([(x.value, x.name) for x in cls])`--either in a function (DRY) or directly in the field's constructor.

Answer (score 8):

Model's choices option accepts a sequence consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for this field.

In addition, Django provides [enumeration types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) that you can subclass to define choices in a concise way:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class ThingPriority(models.IntegerChoices):
    LOW = 0, _('Low')
    NORMAL = 1, _('Normal')
    HIGH = 2, _('High')

class Thing(models.Model):
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=ThingPriority.NORMAL, choices=ThingPriority.choices)
```

Django supports adding an extra string value to the end of this tuple to be used as the human-readable name, or label. The label can be a lazy translatable string.

```
   # in your code 
   thing = get_thing() # instance of Thing
   thing.priority = ThingPriority.LOW
```

Note: you can use that using `ThingPriority.HIGH`, `ThingPriority.['HIGH']`, or `ThingPriority(0)` to access or lookup enum members.

You need to import `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`

Comment: i thought this answer wasnt working, but i forgot "from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _"

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably set up the reverse-lookup dict once and for all, but if I hadn't I'd just use:

```
thing.priority = next(value for value, name in Thing.PRIORITIES
                      if name=='Normal')
```

which seems simpler than building the dict on the fly just to toss it away again;-).

Comment: Yes, tossing the dict is a little silly, now that you say it. :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a field type I wrote a few minutes ago that I think does what you want. Its constructor requires an argument 'choices', which may be either a tuple of 2-tuples in the same format as the choices option to IntegerField, or instead a simple list of names (ie ChoiceField(('Low', 'Normal', 'High'), default='Low') ). The class takes care of the mapping from string to int for you, you never see the int.

```
  class ChoiceField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, choices, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(choices[0],'__iter__'):
            choices = zip(range(len(choices)), choices)

        self.val2choice = dict(choices)
        self.choice2val = dict((v,k) for k,v in choices)

        kwargs['choices'] = choices
        super(models.IntegerField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return self.val2choice[value]

    def get_db_prep_value(self, choice):
        return self.choice2val[choice]
```

Comment: That's not bad Allan. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
class Sequence(object):
    def __init__(self, func, *opts):
        keys = func(len(opts))
        self.attrs = dict(zip([t[0] for t in opts], keys))
        self.choices = zip(keys, [t[1] for t in opts])
        self.labels = dict(self.choices)
    def __getattr__(self, a):
        return self.attrs[a]
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.labels[k]
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.choices)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.choices)
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return self

class Enum(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *opts):
        return super(Enum, self).__init__(range, *opts)

class Flags(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *opts):
        return super(Flags, self).__init__(lambda l: [1<<i for i in xrange(l)], *opts)
```

Use it like this:

```
Priorities = Enum(
    ('LOW', 'Low'),
    ('NORMAL', 'Normal'),
    ('HIGH', 'High')
)

priority = models.IntegerField(default=Priorities.LOW, choices=Priorities)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace your numbers with the human readable values you would like. As such:

```
PRIORITIES = (
('LOW', 'Low'),
('NORMAL', 'Normal'),
('HIGH', 'High'),
)
```

This makes it human readable, however, you'd have to define your own ordering.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is very late and might seem obvious to nowadays-Django experts, but to whoever lands here, i recently discovered a very elegant solution brought by django-model-utils: https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#choices

This package allows you to define Choices with three-tuples where:

- The first item is the database value
- The second item is a code-readable value
- The third item is a human-readable value

So here's what you can do:

```py
from model_utils import Choices

class Thing(models.Model):
    PRIORITIES = Choices(
        (0, 'low', 'Low'),
        (1, 'normal', 'Normal'),
        (2, 'high', 'High'),
      )

    priority = models.IntegerField(default=PRIORITIES.normal, choices=PRIORITIES)

thing.priority = getattr(Thing.PRIORITIES.Normal)
```

This way:

- You can use your human-readable value to actually choose the value of your field (in my case, it's useful because i'm scraping wild content and storing it in a normalized way)
- A clean value is stored in your database
- You have nothing non-DRY to do ;)

Enjoy :)

Comment: Totally valid to bring up django-model-utils. One small suggestion to increase readability; use the dot-notation on the default parameter as well: `priority = models.IntegerField(default=PRIORITIES.Low, choices=PRIORITIES)` (needless to say, the priority assignment has to be indented to be inside the Thing-class in order to do so). Also consider using lowercase words/characters for the python identifier, as you are not referring to a class, but a parameter instead (your Choices would then become: `(0, 'low', 'Low'),` and so forth).

Answer (score 0):

Originally I used a modified version of @Allan's answer:

```
from enum import IntEnum, EnumMeta

class IntegerChoiceField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, choices, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(choices, '__iter__') and isinstance(choices, EnumMeta):
            choices = list(zip(range(1, len(choices) + 1), [member.name for member in list(choices)]))

        kwargs['choices'] = choices
        super(models.IntegerField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        return self.choices(value)

    def get_db_prep_value(self, choice):
        return self.choices[choice]

models.IntegerChoiceField = IntegerChoiceField

GEAR = IntEnum('GEAR', 'HEAD BODY FEET HANDS SHIELD NECK UNKNOWN')

class Gear(Item, models.Model):
    # Safe to assume last element is largest value member of an enum?
    #type = models.IntegerChoiceField(GEAR, default=list(GEAR)[-1].name)
    largest_member = GEAR(max([member.value for member in list(GEAR)]))
    type = models.IntegerChoiceField(GEAR, default=largest_member)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Gear, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for member in GEAR:
            setattr(self, member.name, member.value)

print(Gear().HEAD, (Gear().HEAD == GEAR.HEAD.value))
```

Simplified with the `django-enumfields` package package which I now use:

```
from enumfields import EnumIntegerField, IntEnum

GEAR = IntEnum('GEAR', 'HEAD BODY FEET HANDS SHIELD NECK UNKNOWN')

class Gear(Item, models.Model):
    # Safe to assume last element is largest value member of an enum?
    type = EnumIntegerField(GEAR, default=list(GEAR)[-1])
    #largest_member = GEAR(max([member.value for member in list(GEAR)]))
    #type = EnumIntegerField(GEAR, default=largest_member)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Gear, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for member in GEAR:
            setattr(self, member.name, member.value)
```