# Django: Best way to implement "status" field in modules

Tags: python, django

I have a field in my module that is used to hold the status of the object.
So far I have used:

```
ORDER_STATUS = ((0, 'Started'), (1, 'Done'), (2, 'Error'))
status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUS)
```

Its easy to convert one way:

```
def status_str(self): return ORDER_STATUS[self.status][1]
```

The problem is when updating. I find myself having code like this:

```
order.status = 2 # Error Status
```

Which is quite awful and gets really hard to synchronize. I guess a solution would be something similar to C's enum{}. Or perhaps there is a whole different way to tackle this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Django IntegerField by choices=... name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117564/set-django-integerfield-by-choices-name)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Maybe this question helps you: [Set Django IntegerField by choices=… name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117564/set-django-integerfield-by-choices-name).
I quote from the accepted answer (with adjustments ;)):
Put this into your class (`STATUS_CHOICES` will be the list that is handed to the `choices` option of the field):

```
PENDING = 0
DONE = 1
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (PENDING, 'Pending'),
    (DONE, 'Done'),
)
```

Then you can do `order.status = Order.DONE`.

---

**Note** that you **don't** have to implement an own method to retrieve the (readable) value, Django [provides the  method `get_status_display` itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: Link that works in 2016: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#field-options

Comment: Link that works in 2020: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#field-options

Answer (score 11):

what I usually do for this situation is:

models.py

```
from static import ORDER_STATUS    
status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ORDER_STATUS)
```

static.py

```
ORDER_STATUS = ((0, 'Started'), (1, 'Done'), (2, 'Error'))
ORDER_STATUS_DICT = dict((v, k) for k, v in ORDER_STATUS)
```

Now you can do:

```
from static import ORDER_STATUS_DICT
order.status = ORDER_STATUS_DICT['Error']
```

Comment: What I love about this one is that it's super clean and without dependancies. Most libs or utils give you the same functional end result as this solution but with the risk of breakage.

Answer (score 8):

This is a very late answer, however for completeness I should mention that django-model-utils already contains a [StatusField](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#statusfield) and even better a [StatusModel](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/models.html#statusmodel). I am using it everywhere I need to have a status.

Comment: Another library which offers a similar option with minimal boilerplate is `django-choices` https://github.com/bigjason/django-choices

Answer (score 2):

you can try enum package:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum/

Comment: I don't see how persisting of these things into the Django database would work. Can this answer be extended on that topic?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need your `status_str` method - Django automatically provides a `get_status_display()` which does exactly the same thing.

To reverse, you could use this:

```
def set_order_status(self, val):
    status_dict = dict(ORDER_STATUS)
    self.status = status_dict[val][0]
```

Now you can do:

```
order.set_order_status('Done')
```

Comment: Nice idea, but _**wrong**_.  Using `ORDER_STATUS` as defined by the asker would set `status_dict` to `{0: 'Started', 1: 'Done', 2: 'Error'}`.  Note that the dictionary key are numbers, not strings.  Calling the method as you suggests results in the error, `KeyError: 'Done'`.   Change `status_dict` to `status_dict = {x[1]:x[0] for x in ORDER_STATUS}` and `self.status` to `self.status = status_dict[val]`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stick a method on the model, like:

```
def status_code(self, text):
    return [n for (n, t) in self.ORDER_STATUS if t == text][0]
```

Then you’d do:

```
order.status = order.status_code('Error')
```

Answer (score 0):

don't do all those things.just make change in views.py as follows

```
  context['value'] = Model_name.objects.order_by('-choice')
```

where

```
   choice = ('pending','solved','closed')
```