# django models IntegerFields limits not working

Tags: django

I'm trying to limit the possible values of an IntegerField in my Django model.

I have read through this :
[How to limit the maximum value of a numeric field in a Django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849142/how-to-limit-the-maximum-value-of-a-numeric-field-in-a-django-model)

...and this :
[Set Django IntegerField by choices=... name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117564/set-django-integerfield-by-choices-name)

and tried both.

Unfortunately, when I manually set the value of the field outside of the boundaries, then save the object, no exception is raised and the value is really stored.

Did I misunderstand how it worked, or did I do something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits are applied to fields in a `ModelForm`; they are not enforced at the model or database level (although they conceivably could be).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I guess I'll have to manually restrict the values.